# Can't serve gollum wiki with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

**EDIT**: Finally I solved the problem and posted the solution below.

I have a gollum wiki served by a sinatra server on a localhost port 4567. I want to make it accessible from outside world at www.mysite.com/wiki

I have appache-2.2 server running on Ubuntu 12.04 with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http enabled.

My vhosts.conf contains:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    ServerName www.mysite.pl

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /wiki/ http://localhost:4567/
    ProxyPassReverse /wiki/  http://localhost:4567/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:4567 /wiki

    <Location /wiki>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RequestHeader       unset   Accept-Encoding
    SetOutputFilter     proxy-html
    ProxyPass       http://localhost:4567
    ProxyPassReverse    /wiki
    ProxyHTMLURLMap     / /wiki/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap     /wiki /wiki
    ProxyHTMLURLMap     http://localhost:4567 /wiki
    </Location>

        <Directory / >
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

        </Directory>

    LogLevel debug

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin/   
       <Directory /var/www/mysite/cgi-bin/>
           AllowOverride None
           Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
      </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/src.git
    ServerName git.mysite.com

    DAVLockDB /var/lock/apache2/davlockDB

    <Directory /srv/src.git >
       DAV On
            Options Indexes MultiViews
            IndexOptions FancyIndexing                
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "git repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Sinatra logs indicate that indeed localhost:4567 site is accessed when I fetch www.mysite.com/wiki. But apache return an error. Apache logs say:

```
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //localhost:4567
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1506): [client 93.105.202.224] proxy:     http: found worker http://localhost:4567 for http://localhost:4567/
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1020): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1973): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://localhost:4567/
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2011): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2067): proxy: connecting http://localhost:4567/ to localhost:4567
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2193): proxy: connected / to localhost:4567
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2444): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to localhost
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2576): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:4567 (localhost)
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1743): proxy: start body send
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1847): proxy: end body send
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (localhost)
[Sun Nov 09 02:04:01 2014] [error] [client 93.105.202.224] File does not exist: /var/www/Home
```

The "Home" location name was properly returned by gollum-wiki (as its default main page)
Can anyone explain me such behavior?

**ANSWER**: It helped to change every occurrence of `http://localhost:4567` into `http://localhost:4567/wiki`. I got an idea to try it when I logged to my http server and used `lynx` to access `127.0.0.1:4567`. It was thinking for a few seconds and then returning
`127.0.0.1:4567/wiki/Home`

Comment: That looks like a 404, either because it's not running the wiki scripts or the DocumentRoot is wrong.  Could you add the rest of the vhost?

Comment: So I've pasted my full vhosts.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like:

- Your visitor hits http://www.mysite.pl/wiki/
- This gets passed to the gollum instance running at localhost:4567.
- The gollum wiki sees you're hitting the front-page and redirects to /Home
- This causes the browser to visit http://mysite.pl/Home

  - Which is missing, and outside the /wiki/ prefix, so it shows a 404.

The solution is to ensure that `/wiki` is prepended to the gollum-pages.  Launch it like so:

```
$ gollum --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4567 --base-path wiki
```

PS.  You also don't need to specify "ProxyHTMLURLMap" in your Apache configuration; the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are sufficient.

Comment: Well, this gave some progress! Now firefox says: "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." when I try to load www.mysite.pl/wiki. Do you have further advices?

Comment: Use "curl -v" so you can see what redirection is happening would be my best advice.  It's probably something obvious like /wiki not matching /wiki/, or /Home not being beneath /wiki/, etc.